Cloned and changed people in town or diner following same routines
I'm looking for an old movie maybe from the 90s. What I remember is that it revolves around a younger boy in a smaller town or even a trailer park or camping. He often hangs around in a restaurant with his mother that works there maybe. People in the town are changing one by one and comes in to the diner and always follows the same routine with food choices and more. He begins to understand that something is going on and investigate this by him self and I remember that he sees something In a window one day while lying in a hammock, and gets spotted. In the end I remember him hiding with people on a bus or car that drives in to something, a building or something, and he see all the town people's clones in a glass cage and even his own I think. Maybe aliens.

Reminds me of "Disturbing Behavior", from 1998. Basically Invasion of the Body Snatchers, 90's edition. No aliens or clones though. Just mind control.

"He often hangs in a restaurant with his mother that works there" and "always follows the same routine with food choices" make me think of the 1995 TV movie version of The Invaders.  From scififreaksite.com:

Nolan Wood is getting out of prison eight years after being convicted
  of killing an environmentalist for reasons that he can't say after a
  lifetime as a good husband and father. He plans to return to his wife
  and son, but they are now a family with Jerry, running a truck stop
  diner. Strange things are going on, though. Everyone who comes to the
  diner orders steak and eggs and nothing else. All of the coaches that
  stop there are infested with flies. All the passengers smoke
  constantly.


Yes that's the one I was looking for, for so long now, you are great, tnks... watching the trailer I see that my mind forgot and mixed up some thinks but you still did know what movie I was searching for, of course it will not be as good as I remembered it from my childhood but I will still watch it now.:D

I'm glad to help!  Don't forget to click the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as "accepted".
